# Type guard with complement in false branch

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typeguards

I'm trying to narrow down a complex type using a type guard. I would like the false branch of the type guard to understand the [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) to the narrowed down type.

```
interface Model { side: 'left' | 'right'; }
interface LeftModel { side: 'left'; }
interface RightModel { side: 'right'; }
type Either = LeftModel | RightModel;

function isLeft(value: Either): value is LeftModel { // else is RightModel
  return value.side === 'left';
}
```

This does not seem possible, at least not the way I'm going about it. Typescript is happy to infer that an `Either` can be a model, but it doesn't accept that a `Model` can be an `Either`. This is giving an error:

```
declare const model: Model;
isLeft(model) // ts(2345)
```

Is this problem fundamentally unsolvable?

If not, how do I get the false branch to narrow down to the complement?

see full example in this [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Ainterface%20Model%20%7B%20side%3A%20'left'%20%7C%20'right'%3B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20LeftModel%20%7B%20side%3A%20'left'%3B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20RightModel%20%7B%20side%3A%20'right'%3B%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Either%20%3D%20LeftModel%20%7C%20RightModel%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isLeft(value%3A%20Either)%3A%20value%20is%20LeftModel%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20else%20is%20RightModel%0D%0A%20%20return%20value.side%20%3D%3D%3D%20'left'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20model%3A%20Model%3B%20model.side%3B%20%2F%2F%20(property)%20Model.side%3A%20%22left%22%20%7C%20%22right%22%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20either%3A%20Either%3B%20either.side%3B%20%2F%2F%20(property)%20side%3A%20%22left%22%20%7C%20%22right%22%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(isLeft(either))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20either%3B%20%2F%2F%20LeftModel%0D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20either%3B%20%2F%2F%20RightModel%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(isLeft(model))%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20error%20(ts2345)%0D%0A%20%20model%3B%20%2F%2F%20LeftModel%0D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20model%3B%20%2F%2F%20Model%20-%20expecting%20RightModel%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(isLeft(model%20as%20Either))%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20no%20error%0D%0A%20%20model%3B%20%2F%2F%20Model%20-%20expecting%20LeftModel%0D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20model%3B%20%2F%2F%20Model%20-%20expecting%20RightModel%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20cast%3A%20Either%20%3D%20model%20as%20Either%3B%20%2F%2F%20no%20error%0D%0Aif%20(isLeft(cast))%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20no%20error%0D%0A%20%20cast%3B%20%2F%2F%20LeftModel%0D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20cast%3B%20%2F%2F%20RightModel%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

**EDIT**

It appears in this naive example that `Model` and `Either` are equivalent, but this probably cannot be generalised. I could make some progress by combining two type guards, in an attempt to inform the type system that `Model` is in fact a valid `Either` (see this new [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Ainterface%20Model%20%7B%20side%3A%20'left'%20%7C%20'right'%3B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20LeftModel%20%7B%20side%3A%20'left'%3B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20RightModel%20%7B%20side%3A%20'right'%3B%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Either%20%3D%20LeftModel%20%7C%20RightModel%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isLeft(value%3A%20Either)%3A%20value%20is%20LeftModel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20value.side%20%3D%3D%3D%20'left'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20model%3A%20Model%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20isEither(value%3A%20Model)%3A%20value%20is%20Either%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(isEither(model))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20model%3B%20%2F%2F%20Either%0D%0A%20%20if%20(isLeft(model))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20model%3B%20%2F%2F%20LeftModel%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20model%3B%20%2F%2F%20RightModel%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20model%3B%20%2F%2F%20Model%20-%20expected%20never%0D%0A%7D)). This however leaves me with an unwanted branch (see line 22) so isn't fully satisfactory.

Is there a way to let the type system know that `Either` and `Model` are strictly equivalent?

I do not particularly need to use either type guards or union types, this was my first attempt at solving the problem but created problems of its own. Union types would only be viable if we can guarantee that the union of a narrowed type and its relative complement are indeed equivalent to the type narrowed down. This relies on the type system having an understanding of complement, which might not be the case (yet). See this [typescript complement search](https://www.google.com/search?q=+complement+typescript) and the [handbook on utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)

Someone suggesting using [fp-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts) and/or [monocle-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/monocle-ts) to solve this but some of these functional programming concepts are still going over my head. If someone knows how to apply them here though that would be nice. [Either](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Either.ts.html) sounds like it could help here...

Answer (score 3):

The union operator `|` does not perform a union on the types of the properties of the types specified in the union.

i.e.

```
type Either = LeftModel | RightModel === { side: 'left ' } | { side: 'right' } 
           !== { side: 'left' | 'right' } === Model
```

`Either` is strictly a union of `LeftModel` and `RightModel` not a union of type `side` and `side`

Excerpt of the error, I think this says it all,

> Argument of type 'Model' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Either'.
>     Type 'Model' is not assignable to type 'RightModel'.
>       Types of property 'side' are incompatible.
>         Type '"left" | "right"' is not assignable to type '"right"'.
>           Type '"left"' is not assignable to type '"right"'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comment. You are right. This kind of breaks my heart tho as I would have expect both types to be equivalent...

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this with a type union and without a type guard:

```
interface Model { side: 'left' | 'right'; }
interface LeftModel extends Model { side: 'left'; }
interface RightModel extends Model { side: 'right'; }

function whatever(model: LeftModel | RightModel) {
  model.side // left or right

  if (model.side === 'left') {
    model.side; // left - model is also LeftModel at this point
  } else {
    model.side; // right - model is a RightModel
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Model%20%7B%20side%3A%20'left'%20%7C%20'right'%3B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20LeftModel%20extends%20Model%20%7B%20side%3A%20'left'%3B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20RightModel%20extends%20Model%20%7B%20side%3A%20'right'%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20whatever(model%3A%20LeftModel%20%7C%20RightModel)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20model.side%20%2F%2F%20left%20or%20right%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20if%20(model.side%20%3D%3D%3D%20'left')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20model.side%3B%20%2F%2F%20left%20-%20model%20is%20also%20LeftModel%20at%20this%20point%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20model.side%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%20-%20model%20is%20a%20RightModel%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

The inheritance from `Model` is actually optional, as it's really the type union that does the work here. But it helps to constrain any subclasses to 'right' or 'left' only.

Hopefully this is the type of thing you're trying to accomplish?

While the type guard isn't necessary, it can still be used. It can't figure out the complementary `RightModel` type - but the caller can, by already having `value` constrained to a union of `LeftModel` and `RightModel`.

```
interface Model { side: 'left' | 'right'; }
interface LeftModel extends Model { side: 'left'; }
interface RightModel extends Model { side: 'right'; }

function isLeft(value: Model): value is LeftModel {
  return value.side === 'left';
}

function whatever(model: LeftModel | RightModel) { // This union makes the else branch work
  model.side // left or right

  if (isLeft(model)) {
    model.side; // left - model is also LeftModel at this point
  } else {
    model.side; // right - model is a RightModel
  }
}
```

[With type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Model%20%7B%20side%3A%20'left'%20%7C%20'right'%3B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20LeftModel%20extends%20Model%20%7B%20side%3A%20'left'%3B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20RightModel%20extends%20Model%20%7B%20side%3A%20'right'%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isLeft(value%3A%20Model)%3A%20value%20is%20LeftModel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20value.side%20%3D%3D%3D%20'left'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20whatever(model%3A%20LeftModel%20%7C%20RightModel)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20model.side%20%2F%2F%20left%20or%20right%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20if%20(isLeft(model))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20model.side%3B%20%2F%2F%20left%20-%20model%20is%20also%20LeftModel%20at%20this%20point%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20model.side%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%20-%20model%20is%20a%20RightModel%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: When using the `Model` type instead of the union type, the type system does not infer the narrowed down types in the `if/else` statement branches. Or rather, you cannot use an instance of `Model` as input where the union type is specified (as in, that function)

Comment: The important part is the union should be used wherever you need to differentiate between the model types, you simply can't use `Model` at this point. The type guard can actually take the union, or `Model` as an argument and produce the same result.

Comment: Trying to feed a `Model` instead of a union type in the type guard will result in a `ts2345` error, see the Playground I linked in my example (line 20)

Comment: Yeah that's kinda my point. If you pass a `Model` to the type guard then it will only be able to tell you if it's a `LeftModel` or not. However if you pass it a union of 2 types (regardless of the type of the guard's argument) then the compiler will infer that if it's not Type A it must be Type B. See my 2nd playground link.

Comment: Bottom line is there must be a Union, the compiler can't assume that if a `Model` isn't a `LeftModel` then it must be a `RightModel`, because that's simply not true.